# Monitor network statistics with vnstat on CoreOS?

Tags: linux, cluster, network-monitoring, coreos

I notice that `vnstat` isn't installed on CoreOS. Is there a comparable way to monitor network usage on a CoreOS cluster?  Certainly one could run vnstat through a Docker container but I assume that would only capture network activity that passes through the container and not the CoreOS node as a whole, right?

Comment: have you tried installing vnstat using source code? Have you looked into [modifying coreos using the SDK](https://coreos.com/docs/sdk-distributors/sdk/modifying-coreos/) to include vnstat?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions; but it seems this is a routine enough task for any server that there should be standard way of doing it.  I don't believe coreos is designed to compile software from source, nor does rebuilding CoreOS from the SDK sound like the prefered way to run services... maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: If CoreOS doesn't provide a tool you need, using the SDK to make a new deploy image so you can have it everywhere in your cluster seems pretty ideal. Worst case scenario, you can use `iptables -nvL FORWARD` to view packet and byte counts for the forward rules, or `tc -s qdisc show` to view the same for the entire interface.

Comment: This is what you're looking for: https://coreos.com/docs/cluster-management/debugging/install-debugging-tools/
CoreOS is not intended to have package managers or software installed directly to it, merely to run containers.

Comment: @theterribletrivium thanks, that looks promising.  Though it's not clear how this would work with vnstat, since the toolbox appears to be aimed at only interactive/debugging use, not monitoring use.  presumably it would terminate vnstat once you exited the interactive session, so no logs.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know much about vnstat, but you could use a tool like supervisord to run more than one application and as part of its configuration have it write logs. Here is an example supervisord config with logging: 
[program:tornado-8000]
command=/path/to/app.py --port=8000
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisord/tornado-stderr.log
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisord/tornado-stdout.log

You could then run a syslog daemon using supervisord as well and have it send the logs offbox. There are a lot of ways to do this, just food for thought.

Comment: yeah, seems a bit hacky compared to monitoring network use on a typical linux distro, but sounds like "use coreOS toolbox container" is the right solution here. If you put that in for the answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by passing --net=host when starting a docker container containing whatever monitoring software you need.

You may or may not also need --privileged=true as well.